# How to Use @RequestBody and @Requestparam in post call in spring boot

Tags: api

Someone please tell is there any way to use @RequestBody and @Requestparam annotation in on post call
i am trying to call api using Ajex post call but i am getting the RequestBody missing.
But i need both in one post call.

Answer (score 0):

```
@PostMapping("/data/try")
fun example(@RequestParam param: String, 
            @RequestBody body: String): ResponseEntity<Any> 
{
  // body here
}
```

Comment: @PostMapping("/getProducts")
 @Produces({MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON,MediaType.APPLICATION_XML})
 public ResponseEntity<Object> getProducts(@RequestBody getproductlist 
     getproduct, @RequestParam("prodId") String prodId,HttpServletResponse response){
 }






  Here when i call this api using ajex post cal i am getting Request Body is missing,
  But when i call it from postman 
Getting    "message": "Required String parameter 'prodId' is not present",